# Double underline a field SSRS 2008 R2 matrix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2008-r2

i have an ssrs 2008 R2 matrix with Accounts on Rows, Months on Columns and Sales in the data section. I need to “double underline” the sales numbers but I can’t figure out how to do this.

i tried using “double border” but that would create one giant line across instead of just underlining the sales numbers -  in other words, the display would be a single long line across.

any idea how to achieve this? i am willing to use custom code in the report code. Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit: Adding a screen shot to show the desired output:
[image]

Comment: Do you specifically mean that you have tried setting the text box `BorderStyle` property to `Double`?

Comment: @IanPreston - yes i used the border style properly but it basically creates a long line instead of just underlining the values in the column.

Answer (score 12):

For some reason the `Double` text box **BorderStyle** property seems to be rather temperamental.

This MSDN thread suggests a few requirements to get this running:

[Double Line border turn to be single in Reporting Service](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f93cd843-001d-411a-8bf8-ee0799521604/double-line-border-turn-to-be-single-in-reporting-service)

1. The border width must be **3pt** at least.
2. There must be at least one row beneath the Double border text box.

Let's test this out. A simple tablix:

[image]

And let's set the bottom text box to be Double at the bottom:

[image]

In Preview this is unsuccessful:

[image]

Let's test out the suggestions. First, set the width to **3pt**:

[image]

[image]

Same result:

[image]

Let's add an extra row below:

[image]

It works:

[image]

What's going on here? It seems like if the width is too low, the two lines will squash together. Also, it seems like the border actually spills to an adjacent text box, so if this doesn't exist the bottom line is not displayed.

Put them together and it works.

One more note - this is **not** required for Excel - just add a **1pt** `Double` border and it will be fine. The above series of steps are only required for Web, PDF, etc.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to research on this. The issue I was trying to explain in my previous post is that if we use border to underline, then it will put a border for the text box as opposed to underlining the value in the text-box which different. For example, in your simple matrix report, try adding a field in the columns section and you'll see two parallel lines going across(non-stop, continuous). To demonstrate, i have attached a screen shot in my first post; that is the output i am expecting but using borders will simple add two 'long lines' underneath the values. hop this is clear.

Comment: I also tried inserting a 'line' control in the text box but for some reason, the line shows up diagonally...very annoying.